# How do the various LaTeX compilers (LaTeX, XeLaTeX, PDFLaTeX, ???) differ in terms of use(s), purpose(s), pros and cons?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling

- How do the various LaTeX compilers (LaTeX, XeLaTeX, PDFLaTeX, ???, ConTeXt, fill-in-the-gap) differ?
- Is there an authoritive list of *all* currently available LaTeX-related compilers?
- Which are the most popular, most freq. used compilers?
- Why do they exist?
- What for are they used?
- For which purpose would I choose which compiler?

E.g., I was just reading that using `\setmainfont{Arial}` would necessitate switching the compiler (*from* LaTeX to, for instance (?), XeLaTeX). To me as a beginner in search of sense and meaning and orientation, that's mildly confusing: I "only" switch the Font, and I already need to switch to a different compiler. Also, I'd like to be (made) aware of the trade-off involved, and be able to make an informed rather than a random decision...

Thanks!

---

ps: I'm new to LaTeX, and the following could be applicable:

- a case for a "community question" (or "big list")
- a duplicate question

though the following questions don't seem to be that general in scope:

- [What is the practical difference between latex and pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-latex-and-pdflatex)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex)
- [What is XeTeX exactly and why should I use it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it)
- [Drawbacks of XeTeX/LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex)
- [Pros and Cons XeTeX vs pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3823/pros-and-cons-xetex-vs-pdflatex)
- [How to tell when to use pdflatex, latex, and xelatex for any given tex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/how-to-tell-when-to-use-pdflatex-latex-and-xelatex-for-any-given-tex-file?rq=1)
- [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)
- [The differences between TeX engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines)
- [I am new to TeX. Should I use LaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex?lq=1)

Of the above, most are really helpful and worth reading. A slight shame that they're not consolidated into one or two succinct Q&A's: one beginner-friendly, another geared at an experts' bleeding-edge discussion.

Other related, helpful, non-SX link(s):

- http://www.tug.org/levels.html, which speaks of five different "levels of TeX":

> **Engines**: TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, … These are the actual executable
>   binaries which implement the different TeX dialects. The LaTeX format
>   is implemented with both the **pdfTeX** (**pdflatex**) and **XeTeX** (**xelatex**)
>   engines, for example. When someone says “TeX can't find my **fonts**”,
>   they usually mean an engine.

Comment: Possibly related [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/15717)

Comment: I note that you want 'general in scope', but that does not necessarily make for a good Q&A. Each of the questions you link to takes a particular aspect, while @texenthusiast is a pretty good question focussed just on the engine.

Comment: Is this one closest for you ? [An overview of TEX, its children
and their friends..](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/tex-overview/tex-overview.pdf) or `texdoc tex-overview` on commandline/terminal for TeXlive distro

Comment: @JosephWright` @texenthusiast Naive question: what's the difference between an engine and a compiler? (Essentially) None?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: There is no compilers in TeX (not the compilers as I understand them), there are *engines* and *macro packages*. The over view document is pretty good, you should read it first.

Comment: Yes, it's used synonymously,[Things with “TeX” in the name](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=texthings). @KhaledHosny I may be wrong. see [The TeX program itself is a macro compiler](http://www.tug.org/docs/html/ptr-faq.html).

Comment: @KhaledHosny I guess a C++ or Java compiler is a different ballpark, granted. But I often read terms like run, compile(r), build in LaTeX-"context", which I take as converting a *.tex (ASCII or unicode, etc) file to a pdf (or dvi or ps) file. So in the LaTeX-"context", is there a consensus of engine = compiler?

Comment: @texenthusiast Regarding the [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines), is that a somewhat exhaustive/authoritive list? In particular, does it (implicitly ?) include the "LaTeX" compiler?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Formats such as LaTeX and engines such as pdfTeX are not the same thing. You really will need to read over some of the existing material on this: we've covered a lot of this before.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty yes [`LaTeX` is set of macros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85/15717), it's mentioned in my linked Q & A comments. For an "exhaustive/authoritive list" read thoroughly and patiently [LaTeX companion](http://www.informit.com/title/0201362996) and [TeX book](http://www.informit.com/title/0201134489). Any "exhaustive/authoritive list" on any topic is beyond the Q & A scope of TeX.SX. With TeXlive/MiKTeX [you can read lot of documentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27636/15717). BTW you have gathered good chunk of Q&A in your Q to read.

Comment: @JosephWright I read a text saying "compile with LaTeX" vs. "compile with XeLaTeX", so I guess that source was wrong...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty No, that's how it's often referred to, but 'typeset' is more accurate or less misleading to people from a more 'pure' programming background.