# What is the main difference between command latex, tex, pdflatex, pdftex ... and all the other commands?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

I am new to TeX world, and I use pdfLatex very often.

But sometimes pdfLatex do not work. So I begin to wonder what the difference between all these `tex commands`.

Please give me some guiding information about all these command to make me stay away from confusion.

I will appreciate every comment or answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49/5764); [What is the practical difference between `latex` and `pdflatex`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349/5764); [What are TeX and LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6776/5764); [What's the difference between pdfTeX and pdfLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41031/5764); [How to tell when to use `pdflatex`, `latex`, and `xelatex` for any given `.tex` file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57810/5764); [Is `pdflatex` an engine or a format?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63994/5764)

Comment: ...[How do the various LaTeX compilers (LaTeX, XeLaTeX, PDFLaTeX, ???) differ in terms of use(s), purpose(s), pros and cons?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105709/5764), but the main source would be [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/5764)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `tex` consumes plain Τεχ files, not LaΤεχ ones.  And it generates DVI files, not PDFs.  `pdftex` consumes Τεχ but generates PDFs.  `latex` consumes LaΤεχ, but generates DVIs.

I do not know what do you mean by ‘all the others’.  The one variation I use is XəΤεχ, which always generates PDFs; its `xelatex` command command, thus, consumes XəLaΤεχ files and generates PDFs.

Comment: Was editing out the schwa and the Greek characters really necessary, Mr. Wright?

Honest question, if it is a rule, so be it, even if I think it quite unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by `TeX files`, `LaTeX files`, `XeLaTeX files` ...? I think the have the same file extension `.tex`. Do they have different styles? If so, how can I decide which is which style?

Comment: @lfd: Using plain ASCII makes things more searchable.

Comment: It is not a matter of style, but content.  The extension is just a convention; what matters is which commands are inside.  Just compare samples, or grab basic documents such as _Not so short introduction to LaTeX_ and any XeLaTeX one, and the differences should be obvious.

But to put it in a few words, TeX is the typesetting language; it being Turing complete, LaTeX is a set of macros enabling one to do semantic markup and profit from stylesheets; and XeLaTeX is an elaboration of LaTeX allowing easy use of Unicode, modern fonts &c.